# Elementary geometry in a right-angled triangle

Tags: geometry

Let ABC be a right-angled triangle, where

- $\angle ACB = 90^\circ$
- $AD$ be the angle bisector of $\angle CAB$, where $D$ is on $CB$
- $BE$ be the angle bisector of $\angle CBA$, where $E$ is on $AC$
- $F$ be the point where $BE$ and $AD$ meet
- $|EF|=\sqrt{2}$
- $|AF|=4$

What is the length of $AC$?

Comment: What have you tried, @Bernoulli?  Perhaps draw a diagram of the triangle, with the points indicated, then post it back here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From triangle $AFB$:

$$\angle AFE=\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\beta}{2}=\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}=45^\circ$$

From triangle $AFE$:

$$\angle GEF=\angle AFE + \angle EAF=45^\circ+\frac{\alpha}{2}$$

Now:

$$GF=AF\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}=EF\sin\angle GEF$$

$$4\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}=\sqrt2\sin(45^\circ+\frac\alpha2)$$

$$4\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}=\sin\frac\alpha2+\cos\frac\alpha2$$

$$3\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}=\cos\frac\alpha2$$

$$\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac13,\quad \cos\frac\alpha2=\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}, \quad \sin\frac\alpha2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$$

By sine theorem (triangle AFB):

$$\frac{AF}{\sin\frac\beta2}=\frac{FB}{\sin\frac\alpha2}$$

$$\frac{4}{\sin\frac\beta2}=\frac{FB}{\sin\frac\alpha2}$$

$$FB \sin\frac\beta2 = FH = 4\sin\frac\alpha2=\frac{4}{\sqrt{10}}$$

Now you are be able to calculate:

$$AC=AG + FH = AF\cos\frac\alpha2 + FH$$

$$AC=4\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} + \frac{4}{\sqrt{10}}=\frac{8\sqrt{10}}{5}$$